# How to display a background image for a kivy button unchanged?

Tags: kivy

I want to use a background image for a kivy button. I have used the following builder string:

```
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            background_normal: './Pictures/my_background.png'
```

The image is displayed, however, it is much darker than expected and partially inverted. What do I have to do in order to display my original image without changes?

The resulting button

[image]

Original image

[image]

Comment: You could show the image of the button and the original image

Comment: I should indicate the source of the loudspeaker.png: it is https://openclipart.org/detail/118345/loudspeaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the two colors in your image are grey and transparent (the white appearing areas are actually transparent in your image). In a `Button`, the `background_normal` image is multiplied by the `background_color` which is also a shade of grey by default. So what you end up with is the background grey showing through your transparent areas (white areas above) and your grey appearing everywhere else. So there is not much contrast. See the [Button Docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html) for more information.

You can modify your image (using something like [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)) to replace the transparent areas with a white color, and perhaps change the grey colors in your image with black. The distortion of the image is due to `Kivy` fitting your image to the button size.

Here is your image edited as I described. You should be able to click on it and download it.

[image: This is your image edited as descried above]

Comment: For some reason my upvotes are not shown, but you solved my problem and I appreciate your help very much.